# Issue with tablesorter, jquery and dynamic table

Tags: jquery

I have a table in my page that is defined like so:

```
  <table id="search_table" class="tablesorter table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Planning Estimate</th>
            <th>Update</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody id="search_body">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I fill the table body by this:

```
  $('#submit').click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      var $table = $('#search_body');
      $table.empty();
      $.getJSON("/search_issues/" + $("#folders").val(), function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(index, dict) {
              var $tr = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo($table);
              $tr.append("<td>" + dict['title'] + "</td><td>" + dict['rank'] + "</td><td>" + dict['planning'] + 
                      "</td><td><a href='/update"+dict['id'] + "'>Update</a></td>");
          });
      });
  });
```

How and where do I define the tablesorter? I tried putting this:

```
$(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({ theme : 'blue', sortList: [[2,1],[0,0]] });
});
```

But if I click on a table header, I get this in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined
```

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: try to run a tablesorter after appended tr and td .. try to use it inside getJSON after close $.each

Comment: make that an answer, and I will accept it. That solved the issue, thanks

Comment: take a look at answer there is another way may help too .. Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to run a tablesorter after appended tr and td .. try to use it inside **getJSON** after close **$.each**  like

```
$.getJSON("/search_issues/" + $("#folders").val(), function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(index, dict) {
              var $tr = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo($table);
              $tr.append("<td>" + dict['title'] + "</td><td>" + dict['rank'] + "</td><td>" + dict['planning'] + 
                      "</td><td><a href='/update"+dict['id'] + "'>Update</a></td>");
          });
          $("table").tablesorter({ theme : 'blue', sortList: [[2,1],[0,0]] });
      });
```

in another way you can refresh the sorting

you can take a look at this http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html

Comment: Well, the table is now sorting. However, if I call the .getJSON again (with the same or a different selected folder $('#folders').val(), and then click on one of the headers to sort the table, it appends the new data to the table. So, if the first time I select a folder, I get 4 rows, I can sort that just fine. However, if I then select the same folder again, and hit submit, it shows just 4 rows. But if I then try to sort, it shows 8 rows (each row has been duplicated).

Comment: @Mark duplicated not related with javascript its related with data you got from another file to $.getJSON callback function  so you need to empty the html of #search_body each time you change value  I think try to use $table.html('');  instead of $table.empty();